# Normalize seaborn catplot against another variable

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I've got the following code to plot the count of the levels within categorical variables:

```
for i,entry in enumerate(categorical_vars):
    g = sns.catplot(x=entry, col="renewal",
                 data=df, kind="count",
                 height=4, aspect=.7)
```

and this code gives me a breakdown as follows:
[image]

Problem is, the renewal is highly imbalanced, with 74855 1's and 4998 0's, so the plot is highly imbalanced because the y axis is the same.

How can I normalize the variables with regards to count? (so they share the same axis like a percentage instead) eg, for the first plot on residence_area_type, the renewal = 0 plot is divided by 4998, while the plot on the left, renewal = 1, is divided by 74885. Overall, now they would share a more scaled y axis.

I've tried [How to normalize a seaborn countplot with multiple categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251750/how-to-normalize-a-seaborn-countplot-with-multiple-categorical-variables) but it doesn't seem to work correctly, the y axis is still inequal, the percentages dont add up to 100.

Thank you!

Comment: I was about to advise calculating % of all levels then plot. But then I checked the answerer of that link! Please post data like the linked OP did.

Comment: See [mcve] or better [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on what is needed here.